# Придаточная изъяснительная

Tags: синтаксис

**В предложении: "Не было никакой надежды, что небо прояснится", я указал придаточную определительную.**
Но пособие определяет ее как изъяснительную.
Как вы считаете?

Answer (score 1):

В языке часто встречается многозначность, в том числе и при определении второстепенных членов предложения, и при определении типов придаточных. То, что существительное отглагольное, и есть основание для такой многозначности. Подобные вопросы нельзя вставлять в задания тестового характера.

Ответ "определительное" я бы не стала считать неверным. Надежды (какой?) - никакой, надежды (какой) - что небо прояснится. И в то же время надежды на что?

Comment: Согласна. Возможно двоякое толкование типа придаточной части.

Answer (score 0):

По правилу, если придаточная часть поясняет сущ., то должен быть вопрос "какой". Но в данном случае как-то неблагозвучно получается: Не было никакой надежды (какой?). Интересный вопрос.

Comment: Просто есть существительные, в семантике которых главным является не предметный, а глагольный компонент, напр.: умывание, лечение, мечта (мечтание) и под. Слово НАДЕЖДА сразу вызывает у нас вопрос - на что? (ср.: надеяться на что?). Мечта - о чем? (мечтать - о чем?) и т.д. Что здесь первично - предметность или глагольный компонент - надо подумать. От этого будет зависеть и ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос КАКОЙ? от слова "надежды" к придаточному предложению задавать не стоит, так как рядом со словом "надежды" уже содержится чёткий ответ на него - в определении ***никакой***. Единственно возможный вопрос к придаточному в этом интересном предложении - **на что?** 
Это ***придаточное изъяснительное***.

Comment: Непонятно, почему наличие одного определения запрещает наличие второго? Сколько угодно предложений подобного типа с одиночным определением и придаточным определительным. Особенность именно в главном слове - отглагольном существительном.

Comment: Я согласна, что придаточное изъяснительное. Мы не обратили внимания на характер слова "что". А здесь это союз. Придаточные же определительные присоединяются ТОЛЬКО с помощью союзных слов. Так что ответ в пособии верный.

Comment: Не запрещает, конечно. Я имела в виду только это конкретное предложение. Здесь определение по значению очень категоричное, как бы исключающее другие - отрицательное местоимение никакой. Вот и всё, не более того.